# How to add information from vba to multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim ctrl As control
  For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
      'Pass this CheckBox to the subroutine below:
      TransferValues ctrl
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Sub TransferValues(cb As MSForms.CheckBox)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim emptyRow As Long
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet

  If cb Then
    'Define the worksheet based on the CheckBox.Name property:
    Set ws = Sheets(Left(cb.Name, 15))
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.range("A:A")) + 1
    With ws
      .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = surname.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = firstname.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = tod.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = program.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = email.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = officenumber.Value
      .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = cellnumber.Value

    End With              
  End If

  'the master sheet needs to have a "Stakeholder" column with list of stakeholder the person belongs to
End Sub
```

Depending on which checkboxes are chekced, I want to compile the values of checkboxes into one cell in Master Tab and Master Tab only. Above code transfers the values of each textbox according to which stakeholder the person belongs to (and this is done through checkboxes)

For example, a person named John Doe belongs to 6/8 checkboxes, above code transfers all information to 6/8 checkboxed sheets. but i always want the information to be filled in the master tab with an additional column name stakeholder that'll transfer the names of the checked boxes. when i tried it, it made a seperate row for every checkboxes instead of compiling it into one cell. so i made 6 John Doe's with same information except each John Doe's had different stakeholder he belonged to.

Answer (score 0):

We will do this using VBA and the below procedure illustrates how this was done.

Sub copyPasteData() Dim strSourceSheet As String Dim strDestinationSheet As String Dim lastRow As Long

strSourceSheet = "Data entry"

Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select

Range("C2").Select Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "" strDestinationSheet
= ActiveCell.Value ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select Selection.Copy Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A") Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues Application.CutCopyMode = False Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select Loop End Sub

Comment: Please format your code properly (select and press ctrl-k to indent by 4 spaces and trigger formatting).